# firestore android adding "stability" field in custom Parcelable class while saving

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, parcelable

I have a parcelable class Image

```
@Parcelize
data class Image(val id:String="",val url:String=""):Parcelable
```

and for saving in firestore

```
val data = HashMap<String,Any>()
data["title"] = "My Title"
data["image] = Image("dgdg1","https://someimagepath")
firestore.collection("collectionname").document(documentId).set(data,SetOptions.merge()).await()
```

data is getting saved in firestore but inside the "image" it is adding an extra field "stability" . The out put result is like this

```
{  
  "title":"My Title",  
  "image":{
    "stability":0,
    "id":"dgdg1",
    "url":"https://someimagepath"
  } 
}
```

why is this "stability" is automatically added to the image object.

Comment: Have you found the issue?

Comment: Yes, while serializing Firebase Uses  CustomClassMapper class. The serialize function takes all class-level fields, getters, and its Parent class getters and fields. In this case, Parcelabe is the parent class with a getter method named getStability(). So while serializing it includes the stability field.

Answer (score 1):

As per [@BalaramNayak's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76670310/firestore-android-adding-stability-field-in-custom-parcelable-class-while-savi/76715041#comment135199787_76670310):

> Serializing Firebase uses the `CustomClassMapper` class. The `serialize` function takes all class-level fields, getters, and its Parent class `getters` and fields. In this case, `Parcelable` is the parent class with a getter method named `getStability()`. So while serializing it includes the `stability` field.

You may refer to the documentations below for additional information:

- [`CustomClassMapper.java`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/util/CustomClassMapper.java)
- [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)
- [A study of the Parcelize feature from Kotlin Android Extensions](https://bladecoder.medium.com/a-study-of-the-parcelize-feature-from-kotlin-android-extensions-59a5adcd5909)