# Jackson object mapper adds "stability" field in json

Tags: android, json, jackson, jackson-databind, android-14

I am getting extra field "stability" when serializing the data model. This something that's not defined in the model. This is happening in Android 14 only, so this seems to be working in API below Android 14.

I am on Jackson version `2.13.3`.

This is what my model looks like

```
@Parcelize
data class Address(
    @JsonProperty("line1")
    val line1: String,
    @JsonProperty("line2")
    val line2: String?,
    @JsonProperty("city")
    val city: String,
    @JsonProperty("state")
    val state: String,
    @JsonProperty("postalCode")
    val postalCode: String
) : Parcelable
```

I am doing the serialization for the model as below

```
 val jsonWrapper = ObjectMapper()
 val stringValue = jsonWrapper.writeValueAsString(mockAddress)
```

`stringValue` is printed out as below;

```
{"address":{"line1":"","line2":null,"city":"","state":"","postalCode":"","stability":0}
```

I can't find any reference from where `stability` field is coming from.

I tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and `@JsonPropertyOrder`. That didn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76715041/1676363)?

Comment: It never crossed my mind that it could be something to do with Parcelable. Thank you. I had not seen the related question. I still do not understand why this behaves differently in Android 13 vs Android 14. Do you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Yes. I ended up adding `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown= true, value = ["stability"])` to the data class. That seems to have fixed the issue, at least for now.